# Kindle for PC - page loading problems

Tags: kindle

When viewing books in Kindle for PC, often going to the next page will change the line count at the bottom of the screen but not refresh the page view. Then, if you hit next again, you end up on the next next page (+2 rather than +1).

This happens to me going backwards as well.

Using arrow keys, or mouse clicks, or page down/up all creates this error.

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to the occurrence other than "frequently".

It happens on my Win7 64 bit and Win XP machines.

I've only one Kindle book at the moment, PHP Object-Oriented Solutions by David Powers, so I suppose it could be a problem specific to that book.

Does anyone else have this issue? It is extremely irritating to be constantly flipping back and forth just to get the page view to show the proper page.

Comment: Try grabbing a free book like Journey to the Center of the Earth and see if that does the same thing then.

Comment: +1 good idea, I shall try this when I get home from work

Comment: Other books work fine. It must just be that one. Post your comment as an answer and I'll give you the points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues were confined to that particular eBook. I'm finding the quality of the Kindle iteration varies greatly from publisher to publisher.